# Piecewise function with a function as argument

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to define a piecewise function, which has two arguments, one of which is a function of the other's piecewise argument. I am giving an example

```
X0 = 1.7635;
X1 = 4.4855;
γ[En_] := En/0.13957
β[En_] := Sqrt[γ[En]^2 - 1]/γ[En]
X[En_] := Log[10, β[En]*γ[En]]
f[En_, Evaluate[X[En_] _]] :=Piecewise[{{0, X[En] < X0}, {4*X[En], X[En] > X0}}]
PLot[f[En, Evaluate[X[En]]], {En, 0.001, 1000}]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not defining `f[En_] :=Piecewise[{{0, X[En] < X0}, {4, X[En] > X0}}]` ?

Comment: If I use that it doesn't make any plot at all. I just get `PLot[\[Piecewise] {
   {0, Log[1. Sqrt[-1 + 51.3353 En^2]]/Log[10] < 1.7635},
   {((4 Log[1. Sqrt[-1 + 51.3353 En^2]])/Log[10]), 
    Log[1. Sqrt[-1 + 51.3353 En^2]]/Log[10] > 1.7635},
   {0, \!\(\*
      TagBox["True",
       "PiecewiseDefault",
       AutoDelete->False,
       DeletionWarning->True]\)}
  }, {En, 0.001, 1000}]`

Comment: Are you really using `PLot` ? It should be `Plot` (L not capitalized).

Comment: That is so true... I realised that a couple of hours ago... Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes it is possible.
In your setup `\[Beta][En]` is complex for `En < 0.13957`.

I'd do :

```
f[En_] := Piecewise[{{0, X[En] <= X0}, {4, X[En] > X0}}]

minEn=FindRoot[\[Gamma][En]^2 - 1 == 0, {En, 0.1}][[1,2]]
(* 0.13957 *)

Plot[{X0, X[En], f[En]}, {En, minEn, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, {Red, Thick}}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The non real part, is indeed a problem...Actually `0.13957` is a particle's mass. This computation formula doesn't allow me to go bellow that energy, but OK this forum is not about that. Sorry! Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if this is what you want to achieve, but anyway

```
X0 = 1.7635;
X1 = 4.4855;
γ[En_] := En/0.13957
β[En_] := Sqrt[γ[En]^2 - 1]/γ[En]
X[En_] := Log[10, β[En]*γ[En]]
f[En_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{0, h < X0}, {4, h > X0}}]
Plot[f[En, X[En]], {En, 1, 10}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I can't understand how you relate `h` with `X[En]`

Comment: Oh...I just got it! You give `f` two arguments and when `plotting` you use `X[En]` as the second argument! Nice! Thank you very much!